# What's a half on the clock?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

In my room, I have this geeky clock (click for full size):

[image]

Most of these are not difficult to figure out, but the one for 4-o-clock is particularly tricky:

[image: two to the power of negative one modulo seven]

Normally, a fraction like 1/2 doesn't make sense in modular arithmetic since only integers are involved. The correct way, then, is to see this as the *inverse* of 2, or to put it another way, [image: two to the power of negative one] is that number [image: x] where [image: two times x equals one]. Put this way, a moment's thought will reveal that [image: x equals four] because [image: two x equals two times four equals eight which is equivalent to one modulo seven].

However, simply finding the *multiplicative* inverse would be far too easy as a challenge. So let's bump up the difficulty to exponentiation, or in other words, finding the modular logarithm or discrete logarithm of 2. In this case, 3 is the modular logarithm of 2 with respect to 7. For those of you with number theory/abstract algebra background, this means calculating the multiplicative order of 2 modulo n.

### The Challenge

Given a positive **odd** integer `n` greater than 1, output the smallest positive integer `x` where [image].

### Examples

```
n x
3 2 
5 4 
7 3 
9 6 
11 10 
13 12 
15 4 
17 8 
19 18 
21 6 
23 11 
25 20 
27 18 
29 28 
31 5 
33 10 
35 12 
37 36 
39 12 
41 20 
43 14 
45 12 
47 23 
49 21 
51 8 
53 52 
55 20 
57 18 
59 58 
61 60 
63 6 
65 12 
67 66 
69 22 
71 35 
73 9 
75 20 
77 30 
79 39 
81 54 
83 82 
85 8 
87 28 
89 11 
91 12 
93 10 
95 36 
97 48 
99 30 
101 100 
103 51 
105 12 
107 106 
109 36 
111 36 
113 28 
115 44 
117 12 
119 24 
121 110 
123 20 
125 100 
127 7 
129 14 
131 130 
133 18 
135 36 
137 68 
139 138 
141 46 
143 60 
145 28 
147 42 
149 148 
151 15 
153 24 
155 20 
157 52 
159 52 
161 33 
163 162 
165 20 
167 83 
169 156 
171 18 
173 172 
175 60 
177 58 
179 178 
181 180 
183 60 
185 36 
187 40 
189 18 
191 95 
193 96 
195 12 
197 196 
199 99 
201 66
```

Comment: Follow-up challenge: calculate that dot chart value thingy

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: That's just binary.

Comment: Graphical input!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002326

Comment: Regarding the clock, most of these make sense to me, but not 1, 4, or 5. Your explanation for 4 just confirms what I suspect: it's really a one-way hash function: if you know the value, you can confirm it with the formula.  The explanation (assuming it is the correct one) yields multiple possible values for x. Is it 4 o'clock or 11 o'clock?

Comment: @Otheus: 1 is apparently supposed to be [Legendre's constant](http://mathoverflow.net/q/22266/57164), but in a strange notation, and 5 is due to [phi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). Regarding the multiple possible values for x, 11 is equivalent to 4 modulo 7, so they're really the same.

Comment: We all know (1/2)%7=1/2.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Who said that that `2^-1 == 1/2`?

Comment: @Dennis Properties of exponents. Unless that's bitwise XOR, of course.

Comment: `x^-1` means multiplicative inverse of **x**, i.e., the number **y** such that **xy = 1**. In the field of real numbers, **2^-1 = 0.5**. In the ring of integers modulo **7**, **2^-1 = 4**.

Comment: Modular arithmetic is weird.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Modular arithmetic *is* weird, and yet you probably do it at least once a day without realizing it. If you use 12 hour time, and someone asks you to call them in two hours, and it's 11:00 and you decide to call them at 1:00, you just did modular arithmetic. I find it neat that one of the numbers on this clock is expressed in a way that is sometimes called "clock arithmetic".

Comment: "Regarding the multiple possible values for x, 11 is equivalent to 4 modulo 7, so they're really the same". Ugh, so it's a 5 hour clock. :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
R2*%i1
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UjIqJWkx&input=&args=MjAx)

#### How it works

```
R2*%i1  Input: n

R       Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 2*     Compute [2**1, ..., 2**n].
   %    Hook; take all powers modulo n.
    i1  Get the index of the first 1.
        Indices are 1-based, so index k corresponds to the natural number k.
```

Answer (score 13):

## Pyth - <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
f!t.^2TQ
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21t.%5E2TQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A5%0A7%0A9%0A11%0A13%0A15%0A17%0A19%0A21%0A23%0A25%0A197%0A201&debug=0).

`f`ilters from default of 1 till it finds some x such that modular exponentiation with 2 and the input equals 1.

Answer (score 11):

### Python, 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,t=2:t<2or-~f(n,2*t%n)
```

Starting with 2, doubles modulo n until the result is 1, recursively incrementing each time, and ending with a count of 1 for the initial value of 2.

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
2~MultiplicativeOrder~#&
```

I just used a built-in for this.

Comment: Of *course* Mathematica has a built-in for this. :P

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Of *course* Mathematica has an ungolfable built-in for this. :-{D

Answer (score 7):

## APL, 8 bytes

```
1⍳⍨⊢|2*⍳
```

This is a monadic function train that accepts an integer on the right and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Explanation (calling the input `x`):

```
      2*⍳    ⍝ Compute 2^i for each i from 1 to x
   ⊢|        ⍝ Get each element of the resulting array modulo x
1⍳⍨          ⍝ Find the index of the first 1 in this array
```

Note that the result may be incorrect for large inputs since the exponential gets rounded.

Comment: Also 8: `⍴∘∪⊢|2*⍳`.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
VQIq%^2hNQ1hNB
```

Explanation:

```
VQIq%^2hNQ1hNB

                # Implicit, Q = input
VQ              # For N in range(0, Q)
  Iq      1     # If equals 1
    %^2hNQ      # 2^(N + 1) % Q
           hN   # Print (N + 1)
             B  # Break
```

Try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQIq%25%5E2hNQ1hNB&input=201&debug=0)

Comment: I get `66\n132\n198` for an input of `201`.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman sorry, wrong link :p

Comment: Oh, haha, it's good now. :)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```
f=(n,t=2)=>t<2||-~f(n,2*t%n)
```

Based on @xnor's brilliant recursive approach.

Comment: Do you have a link I can test this at? Doesn't seem to work in the console on Chrome. (SyntaxError due to `=>`, I think.)

Comment: @El'endiaStarman [Here ya go.](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iiqm1on6/).

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: I can't figure out how to test it.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman This code defined a function which can be called like `f(3)`. For some stupid reason, that website won't let you use this function unless you declare it with `let` or `var`. [Try this.](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iiqnjdj1/)

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks! Looks good.

Comment: Additionally, it would be nice to see a full test suite passed at a glance, e.g.: https://jsbin.com/jebetevume/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Pavlo I know lambdas are accepted, but this function needs to be named so it can call itself. I'll add a test suite link when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

Code:

```
DUG2NmX%iNq
```

Explanation:

```
DUG2NmX%iNq

D            # Duplicates the stack, or input when empty
 U           # Assign X to last item of the stack
  G          # For N in range(1, input)
   2Nm       # Calculates 2 ** N
      X      # Pushes X
       %     # Calculates the modulo of the last two items in the stack
        i    # If equals 1 or true, do { Nq }
         N   # Pushes N on top of the stack
          q  # Terminates the program
             # Implicit, nothing has printed, so we print the last item in the stack
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJdTdLz9CNdOv8P9/M1MA)

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
n->endof(1∪2.^(1:n)%n)
```

This is simple - `2.^(1:n)%n` finds the powers of 2 within the set, `∪` is `union`, but serves as `unique` and returns only one of each unique power (and because it's an infix operator, I can union with 1 to save a byte over the `∪(2.^(1:n)%n)` approach). Then `endof` counts the number of unique powers, because once it hits 1, it'll just repeat the existing powers, so there'll be as many unique values as the power that produces 1.

Answer (score 5):

### Seriously, 14 bytes

```
1,;╗R`╙╜@%`Míu
```

Hex Dump:

```
312c3bbb5260d3bd4025604da175
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=312c3bbb5260d3bd4025604da175&input=175)

Explanation:

```
 ,;╗           Make 2 copies of input, put 1 in reg0
    R          push [0,1,...,n-1]
     `    `M   map the quoted function over the range
      ╙        do 2^n
       ╜@%     modulo the value in reg0
1           íu Find the 1-index of 1 in the list.
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 30 bytes

```haskell
n%1=1
n%t=1+n%(2*t`mod`n)
(%2)
```

Helper argument `t` is doubled modulo `n` each step until it equals 1.

Comment: How might I test this?

Comment: See [here](https://ideone.com/d8nGH0)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 17 bytes

```
1oU f@2pX %U¥1} g
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=MW9VIGZAMnBYICVVpTF9IGc=&input=OQ==)

This would be three bytes shorter if Japt had a "find the first item that matches this condition" function. *Starts work on one*

#### How it works

```
1oU f@2pX %U¥1} g   // Implicit: U = input number
1oU                 // Generate a range of numbers from 1 to U.
                    // "Uo" is one byte shorter, but the result would always be 0.
    f@        }     // Filter: keep only the items X that satisfy this condition:
      2pX %U¥1      //  2 to the power of X, mod U, is equal to 1.
                g   // Get the first item in the resulting list.
                    // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>33</s> 26 bytes

```julia
n->findfirst(2.^(1:n)%n,1)
```

This is a lambda function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We construct an array as 2 raised to each integer power from 1 to `n`, then we find the index of the first 1 in this array.

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Glen O!

Comment: No need for the map command, just use `2.^(1:n)%n`.

Comment: @GlenO That works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
2qi,:)f#_,f%1#)
```

Peter Taylor saved a byte. Neat!

Comment: Rather than `1fe|` you could `:)` and then `)` after doing the `#`.

Comment: `2qi,:)f#_,f%1#)`

Comment: Ohh, of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP, 20 bytes

```
n->znorder(Mod(2,n))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 29 bytes

```
$n=<>;{2**++$_%$n-1?redo:say}
```

[Hat tip.](/a/68033)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 13 bytes

```
it:Hw^w\1=f1)
```

Runs on Octave with the [current GitHub commit](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/commit/77a5eba228ccedec8ac0d58d0f1842aba03858cc) of the compiler.

Works for input up to `51` (due to limitations of the `double` data type).

#### Example

```
>> matl it:Hw^w\1=f1)
> 17
8
```

#### Explanation

```
i             % input, "N"
t:            % vector from 1 to N
Hw^           % 2 raised to that vector, element-wise
w\            % modulo N
1=            % true if it equals 1, element-wise
f1)           % index of first "true" value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Unicorn](https://github.com/vihanb/Unicorn), <s>1307 1062</s> 976 bytes

```
( ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨  (     2 )    ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨ 2    ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨ ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨ (   2 ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨    ) ) (  ✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨✨     ( ) )
```

I'm attempting to make unicorn a serious golfing language but that's a bit difficult...

Hopefully I'll find a way to retain the "unicorn-ness" of the language while making *much* less bytes

---

Picture:

### [image]

Uses a [custom](https://github.com/vihanb/Unicorn/blob/master/encoding.txt) encoding.

This answer is non-competing because it uses a version of Unicorn made after this language

Comment: The rainbows and unicorns are strong with this one...

Comment: Somebody come up with UnicornRLE

Comment: Am I the only one getting `((2)2(2))(())` out of the code with @Downgoat's interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

## , 11 chars / 22 bytes

```
↻2ⁿḁ%ï>1)⧺ḁ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=25&code=%E2%86%BB2%E2%81%BF%E1%B8%81%25%C3%AF%3E1%29%E2%A7%BA%E1%B8%81)</kbd>

Uses a while loop. This is one of the few times a while loop is better than mapping over a range.

## Explanation

```
          // implicit: ï = input, ḁ = 1
↻2ⁿḁ%ï>1) // while 2 to the power of ḁ mod input is greater than 1
  ⧺ḁ      // increment ḁ
          // implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 55 bytes

**Code:**

```
N*X:-powm(2,X,N)=:=1,write(X);Z is X+1,N*Z.
p(N):-N*1.
```

**Explained:**

```
N*X:-powm(2,X,N)=:=1, % IF 2^X mod N == 1
     write(X)         % Print X
     ;Z is X+1,       % ELSE increase exponent X
     N*Z.             % Recurse
p(N):-N*1.            % Start testing with 2^1
```

**Example:**

```
p(195).
12
```

Try it online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/wbJDbkIG.pl)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-æ`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
©2pU %N¶1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=qTJwVSAlTrYx&input=MjAx)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=1:2**x%n==1or 1+f(n,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVPBatwwEL3rK6aGwDoJYceSLCngY3vuqadCcbN2anC9i@2Ay7Lfvn0zMgSMx5p5evP0xrr8W/@cJ3u/983Y/v19aml63hp@rR4ft4epafg8Ez/1B2SfuLyv3bL@emuXbqGGiqKwVJHx5MgEsmQS1WSYiY8IlhhF1ioHingnYoSKBVahzgieKqCrkEuJKgTL5PG2SmS9Ell0wDabdOVYtzlAQO8yxAUCq3EgAbNn6ektedGY2/jcxifyCDWEIFlb0VNnjjpQLStwYBWY0N4ESwnvzBEgREIiaDERUqEgWorARy89Y9BTxKQnTKzEKZ8meT1GCuQASUm5@Cie6QfkssSsho8QfBRTj0n3MRhztNqDxV8xGA7rBnhcyRoOsI4BjlQa/d4CVgcJSa1jeM2qQewWRpsVMgyvdQ2glQ947qQA08U2husqAbY7ae2EURI4AWQh2qxlN5/hvtdfIuUI/9EUEZ1rTexADCFqAYxeWmIOqg2D4CBIzEI1YBheC0AG@YiClErcVcb9OBiK03X@CRljSSISc0lST7vjmAznRCI8psJs6hr/ujE9LoPcABom@rwJL8tlHNZD8XMqyldDuEC04XYIYC@VkkVqmNbDJIteAMs6H3CxSkkMveS@NLQJA9HcDktHP9rxo/s6z2cAi2/tMHan3F/60nW6PVO3Xbq3FfnrdqN2OtH7eaVrv92K0nTj0gndZZbGxfd2WQBsx/GTZHkpyvt/)

Thanks Maria Miller for saving me 1 byte.

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU@nwtbQykhLq0I1z9bWML9IwVA7TQMoqm2o@b@gKDOvRCNNw9DcUFPzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=1;(1<<i++)%n-1;);--i;}
```

Gives accurate results up to \$x=31\$, otherwise the result is 32.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCoAgEADQ3a@QQLjDHGw9@5OWUIwbOkOiRfx2840vuivGMZgyCLZcKvDuCXwIbC0acZ6QnGPqg@XV98kCX@GEqik9PXV2hsWkQ5ZVZ9g8Iqk@fg)