# Find the binary period

Tags: code-golf, number, binary, rational-numbers

We know that not all fractions have a terminating binary representation.  However every fraction can be written as a leading portion followed by a repeating portion.  For example \$1/3\$ starts with \$0.\$ and then just repeats \$01\$ endlessly.  This corresponds to the bar notation taught in primary school.  For example

$$
1/3 = 0.\overline{01}
$$

Where the portion with the bar is the repeating section.

For numbers with a terminating representation, (e.g. \$1/2 = 0.1\$) the repeating section is just \$0\$, since there are endless implicit zeros at the end of a terminating representation.

We will call the minimum<sup>1</sup> length of the repeating section the binary period of the fraction.

Your task is to write a program or function which takes a positive integer \$n\$ as input and outputs the binary period of \$1/n\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

[OEIS A007733](http://oeis.org/A007733)

---

<sup>1: We say minimum because if you duplicate a section again it keeps a valid representation. (e.g. \$0.\overline{01} = 0.\overline{0101}\$)</sup>

Comment: I feel like we've had a similar challenge mod 10, or maybe about finding the period of the powers of 10 mod n which is similar.

Comment: @xnor I gave it a search and came up with nothing.  If you (or anyone else) find it I would like to know.

Comment: What do you think about this one? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68031/20260

Comment: @xnor If I am understanding correctly to do this challenge divide the number by 2 until it is odd, compute the result from that challenge and then take its binary length.  Is that the relationship?

Comment: Some test cases wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Is the binary period of `1/2` `1` or `0`?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino the post describes it as period 1 (a repeating zero).

Comment: Almost, I don't think you take binary length, just divide by two until odd, then take the result from that challenge.

Comment: I like my challenge better since the other has a weird odds only input, but I have closed it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2*Ɱ%µẠȧQL
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer, `n`, which yields a positive integer, the period.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99I69HGdaqHtj7cteDE8kCf/0ARMwA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//Mirisa4lwrXhuqDIp1FM/1LFvMOH4oKsR///MTAw).

#### How?

```
2*Ɱ%µẠȧQL - Link: integer, n
2         - literal two
  Ɱ       - map across [1..n]
 *        - exponentiate -> [1,2,4,8,...,2^n]
   %      - modulo n -> [1%n,2%n,4%n,8%n,...,2^n%n]
    µ     - start a new monadic chain - call that X
     Ạ    - all (X)? -> 0 if we reach zero, else 1 - i.e. 0 if n is a power of 2
       Q  - de-duplicate (X) -> the repeating 2^k%n values 
      ȧ   - logical AND -> 0 if n is a power of 2 else Q(X)
        L - length (0 has a length of 1 (after an implicit make_digits))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
Length@@#&@@RealDigits[1/#,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yc1L70kw8FBWc3BISg1McclMz2zpDjaUF9ZxyhW7X9AUWZeib5Dur5DUGJeeqqDkcH//wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,a=1:k%2and(a/k%1and f(k,a*2+1)or len(bin(a))-2)or f(k//2,a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCoMwEEXX7SkGQZipkZBxJ6R3GdG0Q@wowU1Pn6a799/nnd/rfdhUa4q7fJZVIDuJYc49i60oPvehASRs/sFDoKPAvhkuaihEI/9Fe71nJ1RTWwpqUMReGwYHE9N8v51F7UJ10MVn51qgRPUH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊞υ¹Ｗ¬№﹪υθ﹪⊕Συθ⊞υ⊕ΣυＩ⊕⌕﹪⮌υθ﹪⊕Συθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY27CsMwDEX3foVHGdLBc8ZAIUNDab7AtQU2@NHYVvr5rg3NUOhQTRL36hxlZFJRulrn8KSykH9ggo2PpxtlAzQw0faXsQ4ZLLHAFCkUuEZNLvZ44wP7XHNQCT2GghpW8kCc97wNO2A/Kl2VbGNOMpcvxsUGfZjuuGPK2B7@VPKxViHqeXdv) Link is to verbose version of code. Sadly all my attempts to golf this down tended to break on edge cases such as `1` or other powers of `2`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with a list containing just `2⁰`.

```
Ｗ¬№﹪υθ﹪⊕Συθ
```

See if the next power of 2 is equivalent (modulo n) to any of the elements in the list.

```
⊞υ⊕Συ
```

If not then push that power of 2 to the list.

```
Ｉ⊕⌕﹪⮌υθ﹪⊕Συθ
```

Print the difference in the two exponents.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda n:len({2**-~k%n*(n&~-n)for k in range(n)})
```

An unnamed function accepting a positive integer, `n`, which returns a positive integer, the period.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCsIwEADvvmIv2t3QirGXEtCXeImYaGm7DXEvEtKvx9aLcxkYmPCR18xtF2Lxl1sZ7XR/WGAzOsZ0VqpZhj0r5MPSMPk5wgA9Q7T8dMiUqWxN3Fv@WdegT5rMDlZC7FmwSubaZgMpV0dYj8kKblMN/mciKl8)**